# How to create a Change Sets for multiple Soups to be able to rollback if sync fails

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, smartstore

I want to have a distinct "success" value or a remote / local database rollback if sync of multiple soups using the the `iOS Mobile SDK` (SmartStore / SmartSync) fails.

I'm able to identify my not synced or synced items locally but I was not able to find a solution to rollback the already synced items to the remote.

That's why I thought, that it would be a great idea to use `Change Sets` that contains all soups that have to be synced. But I was not able to find any resources related to this approach.

It would be great if anybody could provide me more information about this scenario! Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Deployment using [change sets](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/app_deployment/units/app_deployment_changesets)

Comment: @RohitMourya thanks for your quick reply. The article shows how to create an Change Set by using the Salesforce Website but not the MobileSDK. Sorry if I do not understand the way how it works correctly. I need change sets to bulk sync my mobile app for example hourly / daily.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @zaitsman No, the solution for us (with other requirements combined) was a custom api call.

Comment: @Tobonaut custom API meaning you loaded APEX or...?

Comment: Yes. That was not my part, that's why I cannot say more. Sorry. If you find a better / more efficient way to do it, please mention me!